# How to send and receive data using ASP.NET Web Service and JQuery?

Tags: asp.net, jquery, web-services, asmx

I want to run a web service method with parameters and get method return value back using JQuery.

ie.

client :

```
var result = dosomething(var p1, var p2, var p3 ....);
```

when do something accesses WebService with

```
dosomewebservice(int p1,int p2, string p3) { return "something" };
result == "something";
```

Comment: If you have a choice, you should use WCF for all new web service development. Microsoft now considers the ASMX web service technology (ASP.NET Web Services) to be "legacy technology".

Comment: I would love to but have no knowledge to use WCF yet...

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/wcf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access with jQuery a web service marked with attribute `[ScriptService]`.

[Example](http://www.developer.com/net/asp/article.php/3820451/Using-ASPNET-ScriptServices-with-Popular-JavaScript-Frameworks.htm)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, does your web service call need to be asynchronous? And do you want to return XML or JSON.

If you're returning a string, use JSON - much faster over the wire. Even though your serializing/deserializing (which causes overhead), the overhead on the server/client is better than the overhead over the wire.

Calling a JSON-web service using jQuery - look at $.getJSON.

Comment: end product will not send data back but, i need to send it in order to test. thanks for info anyways